# Webpack: Moving webpack.config.js to a folder breaks webpack

Tags: node.js, webpack

I recently spent more than a day trying to figure out why webpack wasn't working correctly (it was bundling appropriately, but not running any modules like babel), and it turns out that I had tried to be fancy and put my `webpack.config.js` file in a folder named `webpack/`.

I moved it back to the root directory (the directory with the `package.json` file, and it works fine now, but it's bothering me A LOT that I can't figure out how to get webpack to run properly when I put it in a folder.

What am I missing?  How can I get Webpack to run correctly from a folder within the root directory?

Here's my current code
**webpack.config.js:**

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge')



module.exports = {
  entry: {
      main: path.resolve(__dirname,"src/js/index.js"),
    },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "STATIC/frontend"),
    filename: "js/[name].js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
            {
                loader: 'style-loader',
            },
            {
                loader: 'css-loader',
            },
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: '[path][name].[ext]',
            },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    splitChunks:{
      chunks:'all',
      name:'vendors',
  }
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $:"jquery",
      jQuery:'jquery',
      Popper:['@popperjs/core','default']
  }),
  ],
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "webpack --mode development --watch",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.8",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
    "webpack": "^5.58.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.0",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.8",
    "vue-router": "^3.5.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.10.2",
    "core-js": "^3.18.2",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.14"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `--config` to pass a custom config path to webpack: [source](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/#use-a-different-configuration-file)

```
"dev": "webpack --mode development --watch --config webpack/webpack.config.js",
"build": "webpack --mode production --config webpack/webpack.config.js"
```

Note: You may have to adapt the paths in the `webpack.config.js` to the new location if you run into errors when building.